# how to get data grouped by every 5 minutes?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle database, where I need to group a set of data by every 5 minutes..
so I have a table called Data, which have 3 fields

- ID ==> unique primary key
- Created ==> datetime field
- Position ==> numeric ==> can be one of the following numbers 1, 2, 3, 4

The Data table gets populated from an application that logs data...

I need to get the following,

- where clause that specifies a start date and time and an end date and time

based on the where clause i need the data broken into 5 minute segments and shows how many position counts there are..

so example i need the end result something like this,

```
Date Time              POS  COUNT(1)
31/10/2017 6:00:00 AM   1   7
31/10/2017 6:00:00 AM   2   6
31/10/2017 6:00:00 AM   3   7
31/10/2017 6:05:00 AM   1   4
31/10/2017 6:05:00 AM   2   10
31/10/2017 6:05:00 AM   3   24
31/10/2017 6:10:00 AM   1   6
31/10/2017 6:10:00 AM   2   12
31/10/2017 6:10:00 AM   3   6
```

Any help is appreciated... it is an oracle database... also the date is in GMT format and I need it in Australian date and time

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One method would be:

```
select trunc(Created) + (floor(extract(minute from Created) / 5) * 5) / (24*60) as minutes,
       pos, count(*)
from data t
group by trunc(Created) + (floor(extract(minute from Created) / 5) * 5) / (24*60) 
order by minutes;
```

Comment: can you please explain this query please.. also where are using the created field?

Comment: I get the following error - invalid extract field and extract source....

Comment: @user2206329 . . . See if it works with the correct column names.

Comment: same issue as above... Invalid Extract fields and extract source

Comment: `extract()` has been part of Oracle for a long time:  https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php.

Answer (score 0):

I use this generic function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IntervalFloor(ts IN TIMESTAMP, roundInterval IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC IS
    denom INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' HOUR THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(HOUR FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(24, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts) + TRUNC(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
    ELSIF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
    ELSE
        denom := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM roundInterval);                
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
    END IF;
END IntervalFloor;
```

Then you can use it like

```
select IntervalFloor(Created, INTERVAL '5' MINUTE), Position, count(*)
from your_table
group by Position, IntervalFloor(Created, INTERVAL '5' MINUTE);
```

The function takes any interval from 1 second to 24 hours which fits integer in one day.